# Avoid Embedded Controllers for twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to optimize my symfony application. 

To render a template I use the code

```
return $this->render(
    'AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentList.html.twig',
    array('articles' => $articles)
);
```

I heard somewhere that this is very slow and should be replaced with twig extensions.
I know how to use twig extensions but I don't know how to load the twig file that will contain my twig extensions.
Can you explain me the whole replacement process ?
Thanks

Comment: I've never heard that this is slow? Could you post the article ? If if is too slow you may should cache the template and render dynamic parts via ESI

Comment: It creates a whole new request it should be slower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused the `$this->render` method in a controller with the `render` function of twig templates (well, strictly speaking of symfony, because it is an extension).

Using `$this->render` inside a controller is perfectly fine!

There is a `render` function available in symfony2 twig templates which spawns a new subrequest which uses a lot of memory and time. Don't use that If you can avoid it (and you can). The documentation for this feature is here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers